# Python: For loop in a for loop?

Tags: python, variables, for-loop, dictionary

I have just learnt the basics of programming and python, and as part of a "challenge", I have to use a for loop to print out each student's data. I need to be able to just display the name of the student and their scores, not just display the dictionary like so:

1. print the student's name
2. print the student's homework
3. print the student's quizzes
4. print the student's tests

print the student's homework print the
    student's quizzes print the student's tests

But I am currently having trouble accessing the dictionaries' values through a variable (in this case it is "students"). Do I have to use a for loop in a for loop?

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}

students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]

for i in students:
    print i[i] #<------ I have no idea what to do here
```

Please guide me step by step through good code (in order for me to understand it), any answers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have tried printing students[i] but it returns an error: "list indices must be integers, not dict"

Comment: Just use `print i`. Easy peasy.

Comment: I need to be able to just display the name of the student and their scores, not just display the dictionary

Comment: would you tell Logic of calculating score?

Comment: can you post your solution as an answer and not a comment please?

Comment: I didn't realise the question was already answered there, thankyou grc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for d in students:
    print d["name"],d["homework"],d["quizzes"],d["tests"]
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked and I learnt something from this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `i[i]` with `i["name"]`. When you iterate over `students` you are getting dictionary in each iteration and instance value is stored in `i`.

In order to access dictionary value, you need to access using key (dict is key, value pairs in python); in your case you want to access using `name` as key.

Answer (score 1):

In you for loop the i is already the student:

```
for i in students:
    print i

{'quizzes': [88.0, 40.0, 94.0], 'tests': [75.0, 90.0], 'name': 'Lloyd', 'homework': [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0]}
```

You can then display the required information like this:

```
print i['name']
```

You need to read this: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 0):

Okay, try this:

```
for i in students:
    for j in i:
        print "%s -> %s", % (j, i[j])
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Annoted code:

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}

students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]

for student in students:
    print student # The dictionnary, so...

    for j in student:
        print student[j] # Print each value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    lloyd = {
        "name": "Lloyd",
        "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
        "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
        "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
    }
    alice = {
        "name": "Alice",
        "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
        "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
        "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
    }
    tyler = {
        "name": "Tyler",
        "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
        "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
        "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
    }

    students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]

    for i in students:
      total=0;
      for s in i['quizzes']:
        total=total+s;
      print "Name: "+i['name']+" Score:"+str(total);
```

[DEMO](http://codepad.org/F4nfBVVm)